# How to parallelize the processing of tables in a Tabular model while avoiding XMLReader conflicts in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

I'm working on a program that needs to parallelize the processing of a list of tables contained in a Tabular model using C#.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```cs
Server[] svrList = new Server[tables.getTables.Count];
Parallel.For(0, tables.getTables.Count, i =>
            {
                svrList[i] = ServerConnect(connectionString);
                Model m = svrList[i].Databases[database].Model;
                log.Info("process table " + tables.getTables.ElementAt(i).Name);
                Table t = m.Tables[tables.getTables.ElementAt(i).Name];
                t.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
                m.SaveChanges();
                log.Info("Finish " + tables.getTables.ElementAt(i).Name);
                svrList[i].Disconnect();
            }
            );
```

The issue I'm facing is that the tables are being processed in sequence rather than in parallel. I'm using separate connections to the server for each table to avoid the "the connection cannot be used while an XMLReader object is open" error.

How can I modify this code to parallelize the processing of tables correctly while still maintaining separate connections for each table? My goal is to ensure that if one table fails, the others can still load correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `Parallel.For` to a regular `for` loop and move the `SaveChanges` outside the loop. `SaveChanges` executes all the commands you have queued up. It does this in parallel inside a transaction by default.

```
var conn = ServerConnect(connectionString);
Model m = conn.Databases[database].Model;
for (int i=0; i<tables.getTables.Count; i++)
{
     log.Info("process table " + tables.getTables.ElementAt(i).Name);
     Table t = m.Tables[tables.getTables.ElementAt(i).Name];
     t.RequestRefresh(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType.Full);
}
m.SaveChanges();
conn.Disconnect();
```

Comment: yes i know, but i need if one table fails, the others must load correctly. In this case, if one table fails, the entire load fails.